# FileNotFoundException: [Location of the excel on my local] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: java, eclipse

(I have tried all the answers available on stackoverflow and nothing seems to help)
 I have written 2 scripts in 2 different projects in Eclipse (Luna) IDE. This script reads from excel and then writes in it. (Note # I have used **ExcelReadWrite** class in both the projects) Both the scripts are almost the same but only one of them is working fine and another script throws an exception.
   **Error log**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: ‪D:\AutomationMobile\Testing.xls (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at apr_package_mortgage_day4.ExcelReadWrite.save_excel(ExcelReadWrite.java:126)
    at apr_package_mortgage_day4.Driver_Age_apr.main(Driver_Age_apr.java:32)
```

In the above error log, I clicked on Native Method (Hyperlink) and this opens FileOutputStream.class
    Which has - "Source not found The source attachment does not contain the source for the file FileOutputStream.class "
    I have clicked on a button - " Change Attached source" This opens up a wizard called Source attachment Configuration - which says "Select the location (folder, JAR or zip) containing the source for rt.jar
 I am new to Java, therefore I am not aware of what needs to be done here. Please help.

```
//The below script throws error -       

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //start_Server();


            ExcelReadWrite xl = new ExcelReadWrite("D:\\AutomationMobile\\Testing.xls");
            HSSFSheet Sheet1 = xl.Setsheet("Sheet1");
            int rowCount = xl.getrowcount(Sheet1);
            for(int i = 1; i<=rowCount;i++)
            {
                 String age = xl.Readvalue(Sheet1, i, "Age");
                 double Final_Age = Double.parseDouble(age);
                if(Final_Age>=18)
                {
                    xl.writecell(Sheet1, i, "Status", "Major");
                }
                else
                {
                    xl.writecell(Sheet1, i, "Status", "Minor");
                }
            }

            xl.save_excel("‪D:\\AutomationMobile\\Testing.xls");

        }
```

//ExcelReadWrite class

```
public class ExcelReadWrite {

    FileInputStream fis;
    HSSFWorkbook wb;


    public ExcelReadWrite(String xlPath) throws IOException
    {
         fis= new FileInputStream(xlPath);

        //workbook object
         wb= new HSSFWorkbook(fis);

    }


    public HSSFSheet Setsheet(String sheetname)
    {
        HSSFSheet Sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetname);
        return Sheet;

    }


    public int getrowcount(HSSFSheet Sheet)
    {
        int lastRowNum = Sheet.getLastRowNum();
        return lastRowNum;

    }

    public int getcolcount(HSSFSheet Sheet,int rowIndex)
    {
        int lastcolnum  = Sheet.getRow(rowIndex).getLastCellNum();
        return lastcolnum;

    }

    public String Readvalue(HSSFSheet Sheet,int rowIndex, int cellnum)
    {
        HSSFCell cell = Sheet.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(cellnum);

        String celltext=null;

        if(cell==null)
        celltext="";

        else if(cell.getCellType()==cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
        celltext=cell.getStringCellValue();

        else if(cell.getCellType()==cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
        celltext=String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());

        else if(cell.getCellType()==cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
        celltext="";

        return celltext;
    }


    public String Readvalue(HSSFSheet Sheet,int rowIndex, String colname)
    {

        int colindex = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<getcolcount(Sheet,0);i++){


            //System.out.println(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim());
            if(Sheet.getRow(0).getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(colname))
                colindex=i;
        }



        return Readvalue(Sheet,rowIndex, colindex);


    }
    public void writecell(HSSFSheet Sheet,int rowIndex,int cellnum, String wvalue )
    {
        //writing the cell
        HSSFCell writecell = Sheet.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(cellnum);
        if(writecell==null)
        {
            writecell=Sheet.getRow(rowIndex).createCell(cellnum);
        }

        writecell.setCellValue(wvalue);
    }

    public void writecell(HSSFSheet Sheet,int rowIndex,String colname, String wvalue ){
        int colindex = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<getcolcount(Sheet,0);i++){


            //System.out.println(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim());
            if(Sheet.getRow(0).getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(colname))
                colindex=i;
        }


        writecell(Sheet,rowIndex,colindex, wvalue );




    }

    public void save_excel(String xlPath) throws IOException
    {
        fis.close();

        FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(xlPath);     
        wb.write(fos);
        fos.close();

    }
```

Comment: You are sure that the path D:\AutomationMobile\Testing.xls`  exists?

Comment: Try using forward slashes in your paths or even use File.separator instead (it will adapt the separator of the used platform)

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code of the failed method `ExcelReadWrite.save_excel`.

Comment: @Jens - Yes this path exists. Also, I have tried all the slashes :) .please note this same format of path works fine in another script in a different project

Comment: @mumpitz  - I have tried all the slashes :) .please note this same format of path works fine in another script in a different project

Comment: @SubOptimal - I have added the ExcelReadWrite class which has this method.

Comment: Please remove your answer and put the code into the question. Following the javadoc of [FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream-java.lang.String-) the `FileNotFound` exception is thrown when the file **a)** exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, **b)** does not exist but cannot be created, or **c)** cannot be opened for any other reason. Have you checked that the file is not in use by another process?

Comment: Hi I have fixed this issue. How do I close this post?